# How to change a ModelChoiceField's query set before sending the form to user in a view?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have this form:

```py
class CategoryForm(forms.Form):
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.filter(parent=None))
```

And a view:

```py
def category_select(request, pk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # ...
    else:
        form = CategoryForm()
        # I want to change category field's queryset here.

        return render(
            request,
            "ads/select-category.html",
            {
                "form": form,
            },
        )
```

In this view, I want to change `queryset` of `category` field in `form` (based on `pk` which it gets from the url as a parameter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form.fields['category'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(....)`

```
def category_select(request, pk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # ...
    else:
        form = CategoryForm()

        # Change the queryset of the category field
        form.fields['category'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(....)
        return render(
            request,
            "ads/select-category.html",
            {
                "form": form,
            },
        )
```